# Finding whether all points are in a rectangle

Tags: python, point, rectangles

I have two corner points that define a rectangle. I need to return true if all the points are located inside or on the perimeter of the rectangle. I have written code that can tell the difference between when all points are inside or outside, but I cannot figure out how to make it return True when the numbers are inside the rectangle.

This code returns false situations correctly with 'False', but returns 'None' instead of 'True' for true situations.

fc=first corner
sc=second corner

```
def Functn1(fc=(0,0), sc=(0,0), p=[]):

    x = fc[0]     
    y = fc[1]     
    w = sc[0] 
    h = sc[1] 

    for i in range(len(p)):

        p_x = p[i][0] #Current point x
        p_y = p[i][1] #Current point y

        if not (p_x >= x and p_x <= w and p_y >= y and p_y <= h):
            return False

print(Functn1((0,0), (5,5), [(1,1), (0,0), (5,5)]))
```

Comment: Just `return True` outside the for loop, the function isn't going to automatically understand what you want to return if you are done, so it always returns None by default.

Comment: You just need to add `return True` as the last line of the function, indented exactly under the `for`. (Your code currently defaults to `return None` as the last line).

Answer (score 0):

The default return value of a function is None. Just add return True at the end.

```
def Functn1(fc=(0,0), sc=(0,0), p=[]):

    x = fc[0]     
    y = fc[1]     
    w = sc[0] 
    h = sc[1] 

    for i in range(len(p)):

        p_x = p[i][0] #Current point x
        p_y = p[i][1] #Current point y

        if not (p_x >= x and p_x <= w and p_y >= y and p_y <= h):
            return False
        return True

print(Functn1((0,0), (5,5), [(1,1), (0,0), (5,5)]))
```